# STM32CubeIDE : flip pinout not available

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm using STM32CubeIDE to programm and and configure my STM32 microcontrolers.

Right now, I'm designing a PCB with a STM32 on the bottom side.

It would make things easier to me if in the pinout configurator, I could display the STM32 "flipped" (ie as if placed on the bottom side).

There is such an option on the bottom (see picture), but it is greyed out : do you have any idea why? Or even better how to flip it?

[image: pinout editor]

Comment: You should ask here: https://community.st.com/